# Can't understand algebra division of fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I don't even understand the first step. How do you get $\dfrac{(y+1)x}{y}$ from the first part? Can somebody help me out?

\begin{array}{rcl} \displaystyle \left({{x}\over{y}}+x\right):\left({{x}\over{y}}+y\right)&=&\displaystyle {{\left(y+1\right)\cdot x}\over{y}} : {{x+y^2}\over{y}}\\ &=&\displaystyle {{\left(y+1\right)\cdot x}\over{y}}\cdot {{y}\over{x+y^2}}\\ &&\phantom{xxx}{\text{calculation rule } \frac{a}{b} : \frac{c}{d}=\frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{d}{c}}\\ &=&\dfrac{\left(\left(y+1\right)\cdot x\right)\cdot \left(y\right)}{\left(y\right)\cdot \left(x+y^2\right)}\\ &&\phantom{xxx}{\text{calculation rule }\frac{a}{b} \cdot \frac{c}{d}=\frac{a\cdot c}{b\cdot d}}\\ &=&\displaystyle {{\left(y+1\right)\cdot x}\over{x+y^2}}\\ &&\phantom{xxx}{\text{common factors in numerator and denominator}}\\ &&\phantom{xxx}{\text{cancelled out}}\\ \end{array}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That comes from $$\frac{x}{y}+x = \frac{x}{y}+\frac{xy}{y}=\frac{x+xy}{y}=\frac{x(y+1)}{y}$$

You should then view $:$ as division.

Comment: Ah I see it now. It's actually not that hard. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The first expression after the equation sign is obtained thanks to the operation
$$\dfrac{x}{y}+x=\dfrac{x}{y}+\dfrac{xy}{y}=\dfrac{x+xy}{y}=\dfrac{x(1+y)}{y} .$$

If something more confuses you, pleask ask in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Well, $\frac{x}{y} + x=\frac{x+xy}{y}$ and $\frac{x}{y} + y=\frac{x+y^2}{y}$ by finding the common denominators.